# Hover css not working and the container element is left in white background

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and I m trying to create a hover menu. On hover the dropdown comes perfectly. After that, if I hover on the dropown items, it gets white washed.

Here is my fiddle and code for it. Can anybody help me to fix this.

The design should look some what this way in the picture below.

I have tried that triangle kind of shape on the right side. But, it is also white washed.

Can someone please help me to troubleshoot this issue.

[image]

```css
nav ul li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn{
  background-color: #EFF3F6;
}

nav ul li a {
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a:hover:after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #7B8B93;
 position: absolute;
 left: 35%;
 bottom: 0px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7b8b93;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

nav ul li .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown{
  position: initial;
}


.nav-link:hover + .dropdown .dropdown-content{
  display: block;
}

.one img:hover, .two img:hover, .three img:hover{
  opacity: 0.3;
}


.open-source p {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.open-source p:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.open-source p a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.open-source p:hover {
  background: #fff;
  border-left: 10px solid orange;
  color: #111;
}

.open-source p:hover a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-top: 32px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 32px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Solutions</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-4 open-source">
                <h3 class="ml-3">Open Source Solution Suites</h3>
                <p class="ml-3"><a class="commerce" href="#">Dr.Commerce</a></p>
                <p class="ml-3"><a class="universal" href="#">Universal Commerce</a></p>
                <p class="ml-3"><a class="emmerging" href="#">Emmerging Techlogies</a></p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-8 services">
                <h3>Services & Technologies</h3>
                <ul class="list-inline">
                  <li class="list-inline-item one">
                    <img src="./images/twitter-xxl.png" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item two">
                    <img src="./images/instagram-xxl.png" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item one two">
                    <img src="./images/instagram-xxl.png" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item three">
                    <img src="./images/instagram-xxl.png" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item one two">
                    <img src="./images/instagram-xxl.png" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item two">
                    <img src="./images/instagram-xxl.png" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item three">
                    <img src="./images/instagram-xxl.png" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item two">
                    <img src="./images/instagram-xxl.png" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item one three">
                    <img src="./images/instagram-xxl.png" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item three">
                    <img src="./images/instagram-xxl.png" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item three">
                    <img src="./images/instagram-xxl.png" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item two">
                    <img src="./images/instagram-xxl.png" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the background of your `p` elements to white on hover, which is causing the "whitewash" effect you mention. In addition, you probably want to change the color of your `a` text on hover so that it is readable.

Try something like the following as a starting place. Remove `background: #fff;` when hovering on `p` elements and add some sort of color to your `a` element text on hover.

```
.open-source p:hover {
  border-left: 10px solid orange;
  color: #111;
}

.open-source p:hover a {
  color: #000;
}
```